# Using Castle Windsor I need a new instance of an object when starting a new scope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scope, castle-windsor, dispose

I am trying to achieve object construction as shown below which creates a new `DbContext` within the using and hence gets disposed when leaving the using scope. So as shown below I have created two processor objects in two separate using scopes. I want to achieve this using `Castle Windsor`.

```
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            var processor = new Processor(context, new Parser(context, new Logger(context)), new Logger(context));
        }

        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            var processor = new Processor(context, new Parser(context, new Logger(context)), new Logger(context));
        }
```

I have asked a similar question before [Castle Windsor propogating inline dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931884/castle-windsor-propogating-inline-dependencies) which suggested using scopes but I can't get it to work the way I want. See the entire program below.

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using System;

namespace IOCTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();

            container
                .Register(Component.For<IProcessor>()
                .ImplementedBy<Processor>());

            container
                .Register(Component.For<IParser>()
                .ImplementedBy<Parser>());

            container
                .Register(Component.For<ILogger>()
                .ImplementedBy<Logger>());

            container.Register(Component.For<DbContext>()
                .ImplementedBy<DbContext>()
                .LifeStyle
                .Scoped());

            using (container.BeginScope())
            {
                var processor = container.Resolve<IProcessor>();
            }

            using (container.BeginScope())
            {
                var processor = container.Resolve<IProcessor>();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DbContext : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DbContext disposed.");
        }
    }

    public class Processor : IProcessor
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IParser _parser;

        public Processor(DbContext context, IParser parser, ILogger logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _parser = parser;
            _logger = logger;
        }
    }

    public class Parser : IParser
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Parser(DbContext context, ILogger logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }
    }

    public class Logger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;

        public Logger(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }

    public interface IProcessor
    {
    }

    public interface IParser
    {
    }

    public interface ILogger
    {
    }
}
```

On exiting the first `container.BeginScope()` the `Dispose` method on `DbContext` is called, but on the second call to container. `BeginScope()` the `Dispose` method is not called when exiting the second scope.

This implies the container is given me the same disposed DbContext instance when the second container. `BeginScope()` is called. In essence, I need the `DbContent` to be transient within the `container.BeginScope()` and the container give me a new `DbContext` instance on every newly created scope so it is always disposed when the scope is exited.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IProcessor`, `IParser`, and `ILogger` also need to be registered as `Scoped`.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IProcessor>()
    .ImplementedBy<Processor>()
    .LifeStyle.Scoped());
```

Do this for all components that depend on `DBContext`.

If no lifestyle is explicitly set the default is singleton. So the first time you resolve an `IProcessor` the singleton is instantiated, it's dependencies are resolved including the scoped `DBContext`. At the end of the first scope the `DBContext` is released and disposed, but the singleton `IProcessor` still has a referenced to that disposed `DBContext`. When you resolve an `IProcessor` in the second scope the already instantiated singleton is returned, containing the already disposed `DBContext`.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your explanation and you are right. You did mention this in the answer to the other question but In my haste I didn't fully digest what you were saying. The example I have given is actually an example of a problem in our existing code base. I am trying to read a message off the queue and I need the dbcontext to be active during the processing of the message. Some of the objects that are being used to process the message are Singletons and as you correctly state it is these objects that have a reference to the dbcontext. I will need to refactor the code to support this scenario.